# Can't figure out why I'm getting 'Automatic update of links has been disabaled' message in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, warnings

I copied a sheet from one workbook to another. Now when I open the workbook the sheet was copied to I am getting the 'Automatic update of links has been disabaled' message at the top.

I had this happen before. It was because there were some lookups to another tab on the copied sheet. Those had the full file name of the worksbook the sheet was copied from. I was able to do a quick find and replace on all of those and the message went away. This time I cannot find any references like that where there is a file name included. I searched every tab in the workbook and searched in the VB code and can't find any refernces to another workbook. THis makes me very uneasy, there has to be a reason I"m getting this message but I can't figure it out.

I searched the entire document and VB code for references to another workbook but couldn't find any. I thought that's what caused this warning.

Comment: Have you named any cells or ranges - that is one place links can exist that people don't check.

Comment: No named ranges or cells.